# How to combine rows in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to do exactly this:

[Excel Combining Multiple Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526664/excel-combining-multiple-rows#comment357635_526812)

The answer given was "Pivot Table", however I don't see a way to display the cell value (or array of values), as opposed to a count, sum, or other aggregation of the data when using a pivot table.

Thanks!

Example of my data:

```
| ID  | Var1  | Var2 | 
|1000 | apple | null |
|1000 | null  | 8    |
|1001 | banana| null |
|1001 | null  | 17   |
```

I essentially want to merge rows with the same ID, and show Var 1 & 2 data in the same line. Var 2 is always null when Var 1 exists, and vice versa.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your data looks like and exactly what you want to achieve?  Pivot table might do what you want but it's hard for me to tell what your looking for.

Comment: Sure -- Here is what my data looks like:

Comment: (added to the description above)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the `SUM` function here? Adding `null` does nothing, so you end up with the desired values.

```
Row Labels    Sum of Var1    Sum of Var2 
1000          7              8
1001          9              17
Grand Total   16             25
```

EDIT: based on your comment, I do not think a PivotTable will work. A PivotTable assumes you want to aggregated data; but in your case you are using it to filter data. Your original link only had numerical values, so that's why it worked there.

You could write a simple VBA function that might help. You would first get a list of unique IDs, then use a function to pull out the "Var" value you want. Here is a function that might help to get you started:

```
Public Function getunique(rngId As Range, rngAllIds As Range, rngVar As Range)
    Dim rngeach As Range
    Dim tempVal As Variant

    Dim offset As Integer
    offset = rngVar.Column - rngAllIds.Column

    For Each rngeach In rngAllIds
        If rngeach = rngId And UCase(Trim(rngeach.offset(0, offset).Value)) <> "NULL" Then
            tempVal = rngeach.offset(0, offset)
            getunique = tempVal
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next rngeach

    getunique = "<NOT FOUND>"

End Function
```

Here are the functions entered:

```
 ID      Var1    Var2 
1000    =getUnique($F2,$A$2:$A$5,B$2:B$5)   =getUnique($F2,$A$2:$A$5,C$2:C$5)
1001    =getUnique($F3,$A$2:$A$5,B$2:B$5)   =getUnique($F3,$A$2:$A$5,C$2:C$5)
```

And, using your test set, results were:

```
 ID      Var1    Var2 
1000    apple   8
1001    banana  17
```

Comment: This would work for my numeric values, however I do have some text fields. I've edited the above data set to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a data setup like this:

[image: tigeravatar combine rows example]

To get the unique values in column E, select the data in column A and go to Data -> Advanced Filter -> Copy to new location -> Select cell E1 and check the "Unique values only" -> OK

Then in cell F2 and copied down:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$5,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$2:$A$5=E2)*($B$2:$B$5<>"null"),),0))&", "&INDEX($C$2:$C$5,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$2:$A$5=E2)*($C$2:$C$5<>"null"),),0))
```

Adjust the ranges to your actual range.  That is for a pure formula solution where both results are in the same cell.  If you would prefer the results to be in separate cells, or if you would prefer a VBA solution, let me know.

As a side note, if the 'null' cells are actually blank, then instead of `<>"null"` you would use `<>""`