# Merge rows in excel by appending matching data

Tags: excel

I am trying to merge rows in Excel, to transform from table 1 to table 2 as shown below.

Basically it needs to check if there is the same ID and if it is, use the name of the first tournament and just add on categories separated by commas.

Table 1 (before):

> ID001 | name001 | cat001
>  ID002 | name002 | cat001
>  ID002 |
>   name002 | cat002
>  ID002 | name002 | cat003
>  ID003 | name003 |
>   cat001
>  ID003 | name003 | cat003

Table 2 (after):

> ID001 | name001 | cat001
>  ID002 | name002 | cat001, cat002,
>   cat003
>  ID003 | name003 | cat001, cat003

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel Combining Multiple Rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526664/excel-combining-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by VBA or formula too.

To merge multiple rows, check the below URL:

http://exceltactics.com/combine-data-multiple-rows-one-cell/

In this example, you only need to change formula as you need to check two columns i.e ID and Name.

You can use this formula: `=IF(AND(A2=A1,B2=B1),D1&", "&C2,C2)`

Check the below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Good answer. As long as col A is sorted.